# Function where 1 goes to 100 and 25 to 0

Tags: algebra-precalculus

It's times like these I wish I had paid more attention during calculus class...

I'm trying to write a function for a computer program to calculate the "heard volume" a sound makes. Whereupon if something is standing 1 hypothetical unit away from me and made a sound, heard volume at my position would equate to 100 (Which would be the upper limit for volume), and if the same something where to be standing 25 units away from me, heard volume would then equate to 0. (It's too far away to be heard)

Comment: How do you want this hypothetical function to decay from 100 to 0? True sound intensity decays at a rate proportional to the inverse square of distance, which asymptotically approaches 0 but never reaches it. Do you want your function to be linear?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you want to accomplish this.

One way is to just use the equation of a line,

$$ Volume(x) = -\frac{100}{24} \cdot ( x - 1) + 100,$$

which has the properties you specified.

It would be better to actually use an inverse square law,

$$Volume(x) = \frac{100}{x^2},$$

but in this case you can't make it go to zero at $25$.

Comment: Your first expression is 25 at 25.

Comment: @ClementC., thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

$f(1) = 100$

$f(25) = 0$

$f(x) = (x-25)g(x)$

$f(1) = (1-25)g(1) = -24\cdot g(1)$

Setting $(-24)\cdot g(1) = 100 \Rightarrow  g(1) = -\dfrac{100}{24}= \dfrac{25}{6}$

Hence you can have $f(x) = -\dfrac{25}{6}(x-25)$